# ScrollView child layout must be applied through the contentContainerStyle prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using react native swiper. and this error was shown I don't know why. How can it be solved? In the past, there was not a problem like this. It's first time happening. What is wrong?

Here is the image of a full error:

[image: Here is the image of a full error]

```
<Swiper loop={false}
          index={0}
          style={styles.wrapper}
          activeDotColor={'#EEE'}>

          <View style={styles.slide1}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Choose category you like</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.slide2}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Bookmark articles that you</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>like</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.slide3}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Get notifications about your</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>chosen topic</Text>
            <Button style={styles.text} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Main Screen</Text>
            </Button>
          </View>
        </Swiper>
      )
    } else {
      return <View></View>
    }
  }
}

const styles = {
  wrapper: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  slide1: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#9DD6EB'
  },
  slide2: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#97CAE5'
  },
  slide3: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#92BBD9'
  },
  text: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#FFF',
    fontSize: 26,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
}

export default WelcomeScreen
```

Please help to solve this annoying trouble.

Answer (score 42):

Add style like this

```
<Swiper loop={false}
          index={0}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.wrapper}
          activeDotColor={'#EEE'}>
```

Answer (score 34):

Use `contentContainerStyle` props instead of `style` props.

```
contentContainerStyle={styles.wrapper}
```